# Delete command usage after Using it

Tags: discord.js

Im trying to delete the .ping after i just used it, while the answer, 'pong' still remains.

The code below is what i can think of, but it doesn't seem to work, can anyone correct my mistake?

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === '.ping') {
 message.delete(1000);
    msg.reply('pong!');
  }
});
```

Comment: Two mistakes: 1.) It's `msg.delete()`. `message` is undefined in that context. 2.) You'd `.reply` to a deleted message. Did you mean `msg.channel.send()` ?

Comment: @NullDev it still is feasible since there is a timeout before the `msg` gets deleted.

Comment: @PerplexingParadox Still would show "Original Message Deleted" afterwards. Also I wouldn't trust on that (in the unlikely event that discords API spikes in that very second)

Comment: Where does `message` come from?

Comment: @NullDev Is "Original Message Deleted" an error? I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Is it possible to `reply()` on deleted messages? I'm not even sure about that.

Comment: @Behemoth yeah it is, I've tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Like what @NullDev mentioned in the comment, you should be using `msg` rather than `message` since that's what you declared the variable.

Second, is how you set up the `timeout` function. In your code, you set it as:

```js
message.delete(1000);
```

But if you reference the [`discord.js` documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete), it shows you the proper way to delete a message with a timeout is like this:

```js
message.delete({ timeout: 1000 });
```

This is because the timeout is a property of the `options` parameter, thus you have to use the curly braces.

---

But for good measure, I would suggest that you add a `catch` method in order to avoid your code from breaking down, like so:

```js
message.delete({ timeout: 1000 })
    .catch(console.error);
```

---

### Note:

From `discord.js` v13 and beyond, the `delete` method will not accept any `options`, therefore you have to do this instead:

```js
setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 1000);
```

Comment: Worth mentioning is that both methods will stop working from djs v13 onwards. See https://deploy-preview-680--discordjs-guide.netlify.app/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#message-delete

Comment: @user15517071 thanks! I've edited my answer to include that.

Comment: @PerplexingParadox, all i did was change the 'message' to 'msg' and message.delete(1000); to message.delete({ timeout: 1000 }); Is all That correct?

Comment: Yeah that should be fine, assuming you are working with `discord.js` v12 and not `discord.js` v13.

Answer (score 0):

well this one code should do the job :

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === '.ping') {
   message.channel.bulkDelete(1)
   msg.reply('pong!');
  }
});
```